# Drop entire row subject to value in column

Tags: python, pandas

I am facing a problem with a rather simple command. I hava a DataFrame and want to delete the respective row if the value in column1 (in this row) exceeds e.g. 5.

First step, the if-condition:

`if df['column1]>5:`

Using this command, I always get the following Value Error: `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`

Do you have an idea what this could be about?

Second step (drop row):

How do I specify that Python shall delete the entire row? Do I have to work with a loop or is there a simple solution such as df.drop(df.index[?]).

I am still rather unexperienced with Python and would appreciate any support and suggestions!

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace **in your question**. Please also format your code as code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting the error, is because `df['column1'] > 5` returns a series of booleans, equal in length to column1, and a Series can't be true or false, i.e.  "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous".

That said, if you just need to select out rows fulfilling a specific condition, then you can use the returned series as a boolean index, for example

```
>>> from numpy.random import randn
>>> from pandas import DataFrame

#Create a data frame of 10 rows by 5 cols
>>> D = DataFrame(randn(10,5))
>>> D
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.686901  1.714871  0.809863 -1.162436  1.757198
1 -0.071436 -0.898714  0.062620  1.443304 -0.784341
2  0.597807 -0.705585 -0.019233 -0.552494 -1.881875
3  1.313344 -1.146257  1.189182  0.169836 -0.186611
4  0.081255 -0.168989  1.181580  0.366820  2.999468
5 -0.221144  1.222413  1.199573  0.988437  0.378026
6  1.481952 -2.143201 -0.747700 -0.597314  0.428769
7  0.006805  0.876228  0.884723 -0.899379 -0.270513
8 -0.222297  1.695049  0.638627 -1.500652 -1.088818
9 -0.646145 -0.188199 -1.363282 -1.386130  1.065585

#Making a comparison test against a whole column yields a boolean series 
>>> D[2] >= 0
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6    False
7     True
8     True
9    False
Name: 2, dtype: bool

#Which can be used directly to select rows, like so
>>> D[D[2] >=0]

#note rows 2, 6 and 9 re now missing.
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.686901  1.714871  0.809863 -1.162436  1.757198
1 -0.071436 -0.898714  0.062620  1.443304 -0.784341
3  1.313344 -1.146257  1.189182  0.169836 -0.186611
4  0.081255 -0.168989  1.181580  0.366820  2.999468
5 -0.221144  1.222413  1.199573  0.988437  0.378026
7  0.006805  0.876228  0.884723 -0.899379 -0.270513
8 -0.222297  1.695049  0.638627 -1.500652 -1.088818

#if you want, you can make a new data frame out of the result
>>> N = D[D[2] >= 0]
>>> N
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.686901  1.714871  0.809863 -1.162436  1.757198
1 -0.071436 -0.898714  0.062620  1.443304 -0.784341
3  1.313344 -1.146257  1.189182  0.169836 -0.186611
4  0.081255 -0.168989  1.181580  0.366820  2.999468
5 -0.221144  1.222413  1.199573  0.988437  0.378026
7  0.006805  0.876228  0.884723 -0.899379 -0.270513
8 -0.222297  1.695049  0.638627 -1.500652 -1.088818
```

For more, see [the Pandas docs on boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html#boolean-indexing); Note the dot syntax for column selection used in the docs only works for non-numeric column names, so in the example above `D[D.2 >= 0]` wouldn't work.

If you actually need to remove rows, then you would need to look into creating a deep copy dataframe of only the specific rows. I'd have to dive into the docs quite deep to figure that out, because pandas tries it's level best to do most things by reference, to avoid copying huge chunks of memory around.

Comment: Thank you for you quick response! Unfortunately I have to delete the rows from the original DataFrame. Using your suggestion perfectly works for returning True/False. But as soon as I try using the if-command I get the Value-Error mentioned above. Do you have an idea how to solve this problem and how to further drop the respective row?

Comment: You shouldn't need an if statement at all. The boolean expression should be sufficient. You can create a new data frame out of the result if you want a data frame without the removed rows; I've updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Maybe the mentioned approach is too complicated for solving my problem. I have a DataFrame and would like to only keep a specific percentile (e.g. 25-percentile) and drop all other rows. The percentile refers to values in one column. Do you have anonter idea how to approch this problem?

Comment: Are you looking for DataFrame.quantile? Try `df.quantile([0.25])` which will give you the 25th percentiles of all your columns, if you want the only the quantile of 'column1' then `df.quantile([0.25])['column1']`

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution using the quantile-command. I created an additional column with Nan if value in column1 is greater than the quantile and one if otherwise. I then drop the NaN rows and only the first quantile is left. This is probably not a very efficient method, nevertheless it is working :).

Comment: Why do you need to drop the rows? If you're only looking for the values of the first quartile, the quantile method gives that to you already.